# Producer/Consumer FIFO Semaphore

Tags: java, fifo, consumer, producer

so, I have been working on a producer/consumer problem, where I have 10 producers and 10 consumers. The consumers retrieve a number from this FIFO that was produced by a producer. All the consumers and producers are supposed to be working at the same time (they are threads). Now, I am not very good with semaphores at the moment, which is why I was trying to solve this problem. I can't get this to work no matter what.

semPop is a semaphore for the pop operation.
semPush is a semaphore for the push operation.
semWorkPush is a semaphore that prevents multiple threads from working at the same time in an push operation. 
semWorkPop does the same as semWorkPush but for the pop operation.

Also, open to suggestions in the way I write code so that it becomes easier to read!
Thanks

```
public class SharedFifo {
    private Integer[] memory;
    private Integer[] ids;
    private Semaphore semPop = new Semaphore();
    private Semaphore semPush = new Semaphore();
    private Semaphore semWorkPush = new Semaphore();
    private Semaphore semWorkPop = new Semaphore();
    private int numberOfElements = 0;
    private int totalSize = 0;
    private int nextMemberToPop = 0;
    private int tail = 0;
    private int flag = 0;

    public SharedFifo(int a) {
        semPop.up();
        semPush.up();
        semWorkPush.up();
        semWorkPop.up();
        this.totalSize = a;
        this.memory = new Integer[a];
        this.ids = new Integer[a];
    }

    public void pushVal(int val, int id) {
        if (numberOfElements == totalSize) {
            semPush.down();
            semPop.up();
        }
        semWorkPush.down();
        numberOfElements++;
        memory[tail] = val;
        ids[tail] = id;
        this.tail = (tail + 1) % (this.totalSize);
        if(flag > 0) {
            System.out.println("flag is bigger than 0");
            semPop.up();
            this.flag--;
        }
        semWorkPush.up();
    }

    public Integer[] popVal() {
        Integer[] valAndId = new Integer[2];
        if (numberOfElements == 0) {
            semPop.down();  
            semPush.up();
            this.flag++;
        }
        semWorkPop.down();
        valAndId[0] = memory[nextMemberToPop];
        valAndId[1] = ids[nextMemberToPop];
        this.nextMemberToPop = (this.nextMemberToPop + 1) % (this.totalSize);
        numberOfElements--;
        semPush.up();
        semWorkPop.up();
        return valAndId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without having read through all your code yet, the easiest way to do this is just use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E>`, which also has the neat property of being non-blocking (which means it plays nicely with Amdahl's Law.)

Comment: I think you might better go to [codereview stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to post your question.

Comment: Also you don't appear to have posted all of your code.  Where is `numberOfElements ` defined?

Comment: @markspace I didn't post all of the code for the sake of brevity, basically, the problem seems to be with the semaphores alone, that's why. Also, even though I believe it would be way easier to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue, the purpose of solving this problem is indeed to learn how to use semaphores in this environment, including making your own fifo style structure.

Comment: I guarantee you that when dealing with multithreading the problem is never in one place alone.  The definition of `numberOfElements` is very important.  Please post the full code or we can't help.  Please please describe in detail what `I can't get this to work no matter what.` actually means.  We should not have to guess at what error you are seeing.  Providing your test code which reproduces the problem would also be a big help.

Comment: OK so immediately `private int nextMemberToPop = 0;` needs to be volatile.  You access that variable outside of any synchronized block so something has to be done to ensure it's visible to all threads.

Comment: @markspace I have updated the code so it includes the definition of numberOfElements. You are right, I have not explained the error well. What is happening is that some of the consumers are retrieving null instead of the numbers produced by the producers. When you are so into a problem it becomes hard to remember all the steps that go into explaining.

Comment: @markspace, I have updated all the variables that are accessed outside syncronized blocks as you said, thanks for the input. However, I still have the same problem as before, some consumers are consuming null instead of actual numbers...

Answer (score 0):

The way you're going about this is so convoluted that I find it incomprehensible.  Sorry to say that, but it's true.  You have so many flags and ways of counting the buffer that I'm not surprised you have bugs.  You're probably just making math errors.

All you need is two numbers.  Normally a count and a head pointer.  Three numbers will make it easier, head, tail and count.  You need the count if you allow a head and tail to be the same index when the buffer is full.  (I'm talking about a circular buffer here, which is what I think you're trying to implement.)

Here's some basic math equations for accessing a circular buffer.  I'm using primitives here on purpose, just `wait()` and `notify()`, real code should use one of the classes from `java.util.concurrent`.

```
class CircularBuffer {
   private final int[] buffer = new int[20];
   private int head;
   private int count;
   public synchronized void put( int i ) throws InterruptedException {
      while( count == buffer.length ) wait();// full
      buffer[head++] = i;
      head %= buffer.length;
      count++;
      notifyAll();
   }
   public synchronized int get() throws InterruptedException {
      while( count == 0 ) wait(); // empty
      int tail = (head - count) % buffer.length;
      tail = (tail < 0) ? tail + buffer.length : tail;
      int retval = buffer[tail];
      count--;
      notifyAll();
      return retval;
   }
}
```

See how much smaller (and simpler) this code is?  This is all you need.

Comment: yes, that is indeed a way prettier solution and easier to understand. However, I was specifically asked to use semaphores in this solution. Thanks a lot, though!